# Most efficient/recommended way to access a catalog?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk

I want to create an iPad application that is pretty much just a catalog of products(say for example, cars) I will have around 500 products total, and each product is pretty much an image that will load up when the user requests it.

example:
Product_ID: 124
Name: 'myImage.png'

User types a product id, the image will show up on a UIImage.

I was wondering what would be the smartest approach to this problem? I was thinking about SQLite or NSArray. Where the id would be the product id, and the value would just be the location or name of the image to load. Creating a cache document folder? Any suggestions from people that have already experimented and created similar apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add the meta information like ID and the name of the image to a sqlite DB and manage it via CoreData, which has some very powerful ways to access the information.

The images themselves should be stored outside the database as I assume that they are not just thumbnails.

Comment: So you agree on using a DB instead of Arrays to store the 'links' to access the images?

Comment: Good stuff, I figured it would make more sense to use a DB. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

Best way would probably be Core Data. It has built in caching, so you won't have to worry about that. Here's a get started documentation: [Introduction to Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). There are also a lot of tutorials online, but Apple has really good start up samples.